# Url Helper Action Being Executed on Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4mvc

I'm not sure what is going on, but the action below is being hit in the controller.  Why would it do this?  Shouldnt it just render the URL.  The _schoolsService is null, but I'm using Ninject. I removed the attributes on the Action and received the same thing.

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: manage.teacher.changeSchools.open.bind($data, true, '@(Url.Action(MVC.Schools.GetDistrictSchoolsForUser(Model.Teacher.Id)))')">Change</a>)
```

MVC.Schools is a T4MVC method.

```
[HttpPost, NatGeoUserAccessAuthorization]
        public virtual ActionResult GetDistrictSchoolsForUser(string id)
        {
            return Json(_schoolsService.GetDistrictSchoolsForUserId(id), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: If you comment out this line and just write @(Url.Action(MVC.Schools.GetDistrictSchoolsForUser(Model.Teacher.Id))) does it still call the action?

Comment: Yep, same result with url by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the custom tool again for T4MVC, and it must of regenerated something to correct the issue.  It is now working.